# Turning SQL Korma results into json

Tags: json, clojure, korma

I am using SQL Korma to run some simple examples on a DB and am trying to convert this into JSON using Cheshire.

This works well when I have only 1 record returned but throws an error when I have more than 1 result.

Here are the 2 functions:

```
(defn get-room [id]
    (first (select room
             (where {:id id})
             (limit 1))))

(defn get-rooms []
    (select room))
```

and data:

```
(def x get-rooms)

(def y (get-room 1))
```

X is of type testproj.models.db:

```
(x)
=> [{:created_on "2014-04-05 13:19:47", :id 1, :description "Room 1"} {:created_on "2014-04-05 13:20:17", :id 2, :description "Room 2"} {:created_on "2014-04-05 13:20:20", :id 3, :description "Room 3"}]
```

Because y is a Hashmap:

```
(pr-str y)
=> "{:created_on \"2014-04-05 13:19:47\", :id 1, :description \"Room 1\"}"
```

Trying to convert to Json:

```
(cheshire.core/generate-string x)
JsonGenerationException Cannot JSON encode object of class: class testproj.models.db$get_rooms: testproj.models.db$get_rooms@507501ff  cheshire.generate/generate (generate.clj:147)

(cheshire.core/generate-string y)
=> "{\"created_on\":\"2014-04-05 13:19:47\",\"id\":1,\"description\":\"Room 1\"}"
```

Why is korma returning different types based on the amount of records (this would help me understand this better) and secondly - how should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing a function call. Try this:

```
(cheshire.core/generate-string (x))
```

Comment: Thanks - could you quickly explain why this needs to be in a function call? IS this due to x being a defentity?

Comment: You bound x to the function, not the result of the function call. You should change x to (def x (get-rooms)), and leave the (generate-string x)